# How can I change == string to eq(string) with sed in VIM?

Tags: vim, sed

I can replace == with eq( but I am unsure how to grab the string after == and put it back in the replacement with a ) at the end.  Does anyone have a solution?

I was using `:%s/== /eq(/g` but I need to get the ) at the end of the existing string.

I tried `:%s/== .*/eq(&)/g` but when I ran it I realized that is also brought the "== " into my replacement string that I wanted to get rid of.

I guess I was hoping there was a way to capture an unknown string and put that exact string back into the replacement line.  something like `:%s/== .*/eq(.*)/g` where the .* is the unknown string.  The first part works and grabs the string, but not sure how to put it back in on the replacement line.  Especially because I do not know how many characters/words the string may be.

SOLUTION: `:%s/== \(.*\)/eq(\1)/`

Comment: I don't know about sed, but with Perl it goes like ``echo "foo == string" | perl -pe 's/== (.*)/eq($1)/g'``. I switched from Sed to Perl some time ago because I think it did not have full regex power. If I remember correct it had problems with negative/positive lookahead and lookbehind. Oh, and sorry, missed the VIM part of the deal :(

Comment: So when using Perl in VIM it goes like ``:%!perl -pe 's/== (.*)/eq($1)/g'``

Comment: thanks.  I used to write a lot of perl but I have never tried to use it inside of VIM.  I might have to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the text

```
:%s/== \(.*\)/eq(\1)/
```

You don't need the `g` flag, since the "string" extends to the end of the line, hence there will only ever be one match.

Comment: the g is because I am applying it to the entire document.  I didn't realize the \1 picked up the entire string.  I will try this.  thanks.

Comment: The `%` is to apply it to every line. The `g` is for all matches within a line. The `\1` is replaced by the text in the first set of `\(...\)` in the pattern.

Comment: gotcha, just figured that out about g and %.  thanks.  Its been a while since I have used SED.

Comment: this worked.  I didn't realize how the \(.*\) worked.  That makes sense now what was happening when I thought I needed to escape my () in a previous command.

Answer (score 2):

Using a backreference should work:

```
:%s/== \(.*\)/eq(\1)/g
```

Comment: thanks.  I couldn't figure out or find how the backreference worked.